# Chromedriver not found in PATH even though I have placed it there

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to config chromedriver in visual studio 2019

I know this is something simple but I cant get chromedriver to launch

I have using visual studio 2019 and have chromedriver in this path:

*\Visual Studio 2019\Python Scripts\Python 3.7 (64-bit)*

but when i try to execute this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I get:

```
 os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I can't figure out why python can't find it

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can pass the path like `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path  = <Actual_Path>) `

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Users\littl\Downloads\chromedriver_win32") yields the same thing :(

Comment: Add `chromedriver`'s path to your PATH environment variable. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows.

Comment: I have the same issue - did you find a solution?